# Monitoring BoneCP within a Play application

Tags: playframework, bonecp

I'm trying to monitor BoneCP activities from a Play application. I have added the DB configurations in `conf/application.conf`

```
db.default.disableJMX=false
db.default.statisticsEnabled=true
```

When starting the Play application I added the relevant flags to enable JMX as well

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5678 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Application is starting without an issue, but when I try to connect from `jconsole` it gives me a "Connection Failed" error.

Are there any other configurations/steps that I need to do in order to get this properly working.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a remote server? If so, you're missing `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<remote address>`

Comment: No, I'm trying to connect to my local server (localhost)

Comment: Is the error ConnectionFailedSSL that allows you to choose Cancel/Insecure, or something else?

Comment: Yes that's the error I'm getting.

Comment: And if you press the Insecure button?

Comment: It gives a connection failed error continuously

Comment: Try starting jconsole with the debug flag: `jconsole -debug`, and see what kind of exception it throws.